# where should I get Images for website?

Tags: website-design, stock-images, website-templates

I'm working on a PSD mockup for a website. I'm really getting hard time searching the right images for slider and related stuff. I looked through stock images and they are expensive!

What is the solution for this? What do you people get your picture for your project?

Thanks

Comment: If it's a mockup, you can download the watermarked comps for free. It's only when the client chooses final images that you pay for them, and then the client should be paying, not you (or you get reimbursed). But yes, good images are not cheap, nor should they be.

Comment: What's your budget. If its high, have a pro take the photos, then you can have them meat all your specifications.

Answer (score -1):

Or probably you could go up here - http://www.freeimages.com/ for free stock images.